# Hot to setup a wireless acces point that requiere web register?

Tags: networking, wifi

we are setting up a wifi network and we need the users to be able to connect to the wifi without internet connectivity. Any request should lead them to a web portal that will ask them for certain credentails and after that the web app will "grant" them internet acces.

I have been thinking in setting up a computer as a firewall between the wifi and the router or find some kind of wifi acces point that i can configure via web service.

Got any advice? The network is small, something like a lobby with 50-100 guests at the time.

Thanks

Comment: What you refer to is called a captive portal. What have you tried?

Comment: Some wifi routers, for example from mikrotik (I think also those from ubiquity), include hotspot functionality

Answer (score 2):

This is routine stuff and has been solved quite elegantly by wireless infrastructure device manufacturers.

Buy one or more [Cisco Meraki access points](https://meraki.cisco.com/products/wireless/mr18) and the process of creating the captive portal with a *splash page* or self-service authentication is extremely easy.

---

[image]

[image]